# Postfix Mail Filter Stops Delivering Mail

Tags: postfix, email, troubleshooting, amavis, diagnostic

I have an internet facing postfix mail filter (debian lenny) that sits in front of all our other mailservers on our network, and scans our mail using **amavisd-new**, **clamav**, **spamassassin**, and **policy-weightd**.

This server was set up and configured using the document found here: http://www200.pair.com/mecham/spam/spamfilter20090215.html
(I also set up the bayesean and AWL lists with MySQL, and installed policy-weightd as described on the same site)

These servers (I have 2) have been running great for a couple of years now (on Debian Etch), but this latest install **locks up about once per day** (at different times) somehow, and I can't figure out why.

**Details of problem**

1. The mail queues up on the server, and running mailq lists a bunch of items with *(delivery temporarily suspended: conversation with 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1] timed out while receiving the initial server greeting)*
2. Running *amavisd-nanny* freezes, and I have to log out of the ssh session.  Running amavisd-nanny on a working system will show me the state of each amavisd process, and occasionally find *stuck processes* (**what causes these stuck proccesses??**) and terminate them.  (I have set up a cron job to run amavisd-nanny hourly to clear these stuck processes, however, even that isn't enough to keep things running)
3. ps -ef|grep amavisd lists all of my amavisd processes (12 of them) with *(ch#-accept)* after them.  On a working system these say either *(virgin child)* or *(ch#-avail)*
4. Memory, Diskspace, or number of postfix processes do not appear to be the problem.

What should I be doing to further diagnose my problem?  I am not looking for a workaround, I want to determine what is going wrong and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

strace one of the stuck processes. It might give you a hint what's wrong.

strace -p PROCESSIDOFSTUCKPROCESS

Cheers

Comment: Thank you, I will try that the next time it crashes.  I tried "lsof -p PID", which gave me a great list of things I didn't know what to do with.  Hopefully strace will be more helpful!